# Password Hash Approach

Tags: security, encryption, hash

> I need to store the hashed password in the database the first time the user registers into the system. The standard approach is to take the `Password` and a `salt`, append them and use a hash algorithm whose output is saved in the database.
>
> I am going to use `Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator`**(CSPRNG)** for generating the `salt`. The salt generated using `CSPRNG` are very secured for generating `salts` as I have read from sources [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). Since the `salt` is very difficult to predict, using the `MD5` for hashing the final `String(Password || salt)` is a good decision or is there any better alternative ?

**NOTE:**

> The parameters I am considering for choosing a Hash Algorithm:
>   1) The security should be considerably good.
>   2) The hashing algorithm should be fast enough to not hinder the user experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been covered time and time again all over the internet, but here we go, once more...

Use bcrypt, argon2 or PBKDF2.  Use a CSPRNG to generate a salt.  Storing the salt with the hash is fine.  Don't use MD5, SHA256, or anything else without an intentional iteration count.

Comment: If CSPRNG generates a truly random string, then how will the the attacker be able to crack the hash of the string(Password || salt) ?

Comment: How much delay I can expect using a bcrypt for hashing and generating a salt using CSPRNG?

Comment: Well, it doesn't generate a truly random string.  Hence the pseudo.  That is irrelevant though.  The idea is that calculating an MD5 hash takes no time at all.  Calculating with one of the algorithms above can take as long as the developer likes.  Normally around ~100ms.

Comment: @Manya 1. You **want** about 100ms of CPU time consumed, that is what makes a brute force attack unattractive. 2. The salt is recorded with the hashed password along with an iteration count and perhaps an algorithm indicator.